# How to edit a kubernetes resource from a shell script

Tags: shell, sed, kubectl

I went through the documentation to edit kubernetes resource using [`kubectl edit`](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_edit/) command. Once I execute the command, the file in YAML-format is opened in the editor where I can change the values as per requirement and save it.  I am trying to execute these steps by means of `sed`. How can the following steps be achieved?

1. Execute `kubectl edit` for a deployment resource
2. Set a value from `true` to `false` (using sed)
3. Save the changes

I tried to achieve this in the following way :

```
$ kubectl edit deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system | \
   sed -i "s/\(automountServiceAccountToken:.*$\)/automountServiceAccountToken: true/g"`
```

Comment: Please post samples of the Input and expected output in your post too.

Comment: How should that command ever work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your command is missing a backtick. But even though you put it there, it won't work. The reason is because when you do `kubectl edit ...`, it edits the file on vim. I am not sure sed would work on vim though. Even though if it does, the output goes to a file, so you get the `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal` error, which I don't know how to solve.

I would recommend you to get the file and save it. Replace the desired parameters and run it again:

```
kubectl get deploy tiller-deploy -n kube-system -o yaml > tiller.yaml && sed -i "s/automountServiceAccountToken:.*$/automountServiceAccountToken: true/g" tiller.yaml && kubectl replace -f tiller.yaml
```

I tried the command above and it worked.

Note: no need to add `-n kube-system` as the yaml file already contains the namespace.

Answer (score 11):

I just found a less convoluted way of doing this:

```
KUBE_EDITOR="sed -i s/SOMETHING TO CHANGE/CHANGED/g" kubectl edit resource -n your-ns
```

Comment: I got this 

error: there was a problem with the editor "sed -i s/role: webserver/role: apache2/g"

Comment: @Andrew While KUBE_EDITOR environment variable with sed might bring you some convenience, be aware of the separator ('/'). Either you single quote it, e.g. KUBE_EDITOR="sed -i 's/role: webserver/role: apache2/g'" kubectl ..., or choose the separator other than '/', e.g. '%'.

Comment: I really like this hackish answer. But how about situation where you need multiple edits in a row and the best way is to pipe the file through multiple sed commands?

Answer (score 7):

I automate through piping the commands through `sed` command without creating a temporary file. Take the below example, where I am replacing nameserver `8.8.8.8` with `1.1.1.1`

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get configmap/kube-dns -o yaml | sed "s/8.8.8.8/1.1.1.1/" | kubectl replace -f -
```

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to do this, just use [kubectl-patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) instead of sed.

```
$ kubectl patch deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system --patch '{"map": {"to": {"the": {"key": {"automountServiceAccountToken": "true"}}}}}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, @suren for giving what I really looking for, but you don't need to save it in a file. you can directly do `kubectl replace` using pipe operations

```
kubectl get deploy test-deploy  -o yaml | sed "s/find/replace/g" | kubectl replace -f -
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know kubectl but doc seems to explain that it extract data, edit from an editor than send back, not sure sed pipe work in this case

if piping wokrs
Don't use -i, you don't change a file in a pipe

```
kubectl edit deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system | \
 sed 's/automountServiceAccountToken:.*$/automountServiceAccountToken: true/g'
```

if editing a file (and using group in sed)

```
kubectl edit deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system > YourCOnfigFile && \
 sed -i 's/\(automountServiceAccountToken:\).*$/\1 true/g' YourConfigFile \
 && Some kubectl to send back YourConfigFile
```

Comment: `kubectl edit deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system > YourCOnfigFile` would throw an error